# How to setup Nginx to run PHP/Laravel API with frontend vue app on same domain

Tags: php, api, vue.js, nginx, laravel-8

I am trying to implement a frontend (vue) with a backend (laravel) inside an nginx server in AWS. What I am trying to do is connect to the API, but when I try access my application or enter data, I only get 405 (Not Allowed) errors), if anyone knows, would you be so kind as to guide me please to know what I'm wrong.

this is my config in nginx:

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name 54.161.224.151;

    root /var/www/backend/public; # Ruta a la carpeta "public" de aplicación Laravel

    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock; # Version puede variar
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Configuración adicional para Laravel (si es necesario)
    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 54.161.224.151;

    root /var/www/frontend/dist; # Ruta a la carpeta "dist" de aplicación Vue

    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

I tried different nginx configurations, but always with the same result, I know that there is something that I am doing wrong, but I still don't know what it is, what I hope is that I can connect the frontend with the backend with the api

Comment: `405` is `*Method* Not Allowed` (so calling `POST` on an `GET` route for instance). Maybe this helps you in any way.

Comment: I'd suggest that you test it on your development server see if the error is production only. Besides that, I suggest that you provide more information regarding the error by providing screenshot of the error on inspect tool or from anywhere else that could give more information about it. But regardless, I suspect it is calling something like `axios.get()` on `Route::post` based on the error you've mentioned